# JMenu as JRadioButtonMenuItem with submenu

Tags: java, swing, jmenu, jpopupmenu

I have a requirement where-in I have a JPopupMenu as a right click menu. I have some JMenus as part of the JPopupMenu which are like modes and all of them have sub menu options as SliderMenuItems(custom), JCheckBoxMenuItems and JRadioButtonMenuItems.

I need to have radio buttons for JMenus to indicate the selection of a mode and the behavior should be as in JRadioButtonMenuItem, i.e. the radiobutton should be selected on mouse-click and not on mouse-hover.

I was able to add radio button icon by extending the BasicMenuUI and setting the checkIcon in installDefaults method.

But I am not able to have that click behavior as in JRadioButtonMenuItem, since the JMenu selects the button icon on mouse over.

Can somebody please suggest a way to create a JMenu with radio button in the menu and a submenu with different menuitems.

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 1):

- In AWT and Swing isn‘t possible without dirty hack to displaying [two lightweight or heavyweight popup in the same time](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=4799266),
- safest way is only to replace `JPopup` with undecorated [JDialog or JWindow](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/toplevel.html)
- this issue is for example for [JComboBox in the JPopupMenu](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=4799266) e.i.

Comment: That would be the last resort that I would like to take - to use JDialog. Can you please suggest anything else that you have tried.

Comment: one of dirty hacks is that you to setLightWeightPopupEnabled, you can to test that,